# A generic error occurred in GDI+ while trying to print streams

Tags: c#, pdf, stream

So I have a function that renders a Queue Stream class.  Based on a conditional, I would like to add an additional byte array to this queue.  I thought I could do this by converting the byte array to a stream, and then Enqueueing it with this additional stream.

I do notice that the count of the streams goes up after enqueueing the original stream, and I pass that into a function that prints the streams. This is where I receive the exception "A generic error occured in GDI+."

EDIT: After going through each page, I realized that when combining the TermsandConditions Byte array to the Stream Queue, it was showing as just one byte Array, where as the T&C's is 2 pdfs.

So my next question is how to convert a pdf to an image?

Here's the function where I'm combining the queues:

```
 internal static void DoPrintInvoice(int orderID, SalesOrderBLL.DocumentType doctype, string printer, int copies, List<string> lines)
    {
        using (var context = rempscoDataContext.CreateReadOnlyContext())
        using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("DoPrintInvoice()"))
        {

            // Generate Report
            using (var report = GetSalesOrderReport(orderID, _DocumentTypeDescriptions[doctype], doctype != DocumentType.InvoiceLetterhead, lines))
            {
                // render queue streams for printing
                var streams = PrintingBLL.RenderStreams(report, landscape: false);
                //add additional byte array to stream.

                var TermsAndConditions = GetTermsAndConditions().ToArray();
                Stream TCStream = new MemoryStream(TermsAndConditions);

                if (doctype == DocumentType.OrderAcknowledgement)
                {
                    streams.Enqueue(TCStream);   
                }

                // render and save pdf in background, print report

                BackgroundTask.ParallelInvoke(
                        () => SaveSalesOrderPDF(orderID, doctype, report),
                        () => PrintingBLL.PrintStreams(streams,  string.Format("Sales Order ({0})", report.DisplayName), printer, copies, false)
                        );
            }
        }
    }
```

Then here's the PrintStreams function:

```
internal static void PrintStreams(Queue<Stream> streams, string documentName, string printer, int copies, bool landscape)
if (copies > 0)
        {
            // get printer details
            using (var pd = new PrintDocument())
            {
                lock (_PrintLock)
                {
                    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer.Trim();
                    if (!pd.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("Invalid printer \"{0}\".  Please try again with a different printer.", printer));
                }

                pd.DocumentName = documentName;
                pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
                pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = (short)copies;
                pd.PrinterSettings.Collate = true;
                pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Cast<PaperSize>().First(ps => ps.Kind == PaperKind.Letter);
                pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = landscape;
                pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins()
                {
                    Top = 0,
                    Bottom = 0,
                    Left = 0,
                    Right = 0,
                };

                var numPages = streams.Count;
                var currentPage = 0;


                pd.PrintPage += (s, ev) =>
                {
                    BackgroundTask.SetCurrentStatus(
                        currentPage / numPages,
                        string.Format("Printing page {0} of {1}. [{2}]", currentPage, numPages, documentName));

                    // get next page
                    var ms = streams.Dequeue();

                    // if we have any streams left, then we have another page
                    ev.HasMorePages = streams.Any();

                    // reset stream
                    ms.Position = 0;

                    // read page image
                    var image = new Metafile(ms);

                    var r = new Rectangle()
                    {
                        X = 0,
                        Y = 0,
                        Width = 825,
                        Height = 1075,
                    };

                    if (landscape)
                    {
                        r.Height = 825;
                        r.Width = 1075;
                    }

                    // draw image directly on page
                    ev.Graphics.DrawImage(image, r);

                    // destroy stream
                    ms.Close();

                    currentPage++;
                };

                try
                {
                    lock (_PrintLock)
                        pd.Print();

                    BackgroundTask.SetCurrentStatus(100, string.Format("Finished printing {0}", documentName));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    BackgroundTask.SetCurrentStatus(0, string.Format("Printing Error: {0}", e.Message));
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        string.Format("The document failed to print.  Arguments were: documentName = {0}; printer = {1}; copies = {2}; landscape = {3}",
                            documentName,
                            printer,
                            copies,
                            landscape),
                        e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you testing for an underflow of the stream?  The printer could be printing faster than the data is being sent!  Using a circular buffer would be better so you don't use a lot of memory.  With a stream the entire document will eventually get loaded into the stream using a lot of memory.

Comment: Yes, it does cause a lot of overhead, I've noticed.  However, would this cause this GDI generic error?

Comment: I think you are getting an underflow.   You need to check if the stream has data before running the print code.

Comment: I think you're right. The first 5 pages are images, the last 2 are PDFs.  So the queue only has 6 streams, it bombs on the last one because it thinks it's the same as the previous 5. So underflow is where the last one doesn't fit basically?

Comment: The sender is probably opening up 7 files.  So there is a pause between each file being sent because of the time it takes to open a file.